# Problema usando el metodo treat de CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Estoy trabajando con CriteriaBuilder de JPA y estoy tratando de usar su método treat para poder hacer uso de clases genéricas y de herencia. El caso es el siguiente:

**Tengo las siguientes clases** 
 
**BussinesUnitParent (Clase Padre)**

```
package cl.tuten.alma.bo.tds;

import javax.persistence.*;

@MappedSuperclass
public class BussinesUnitParent {

    @JoinColumn(name = "business_unit_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private TutenBusinessUnit businessUnit;

    public TutenBusinessUnit getBusinessUnit() {
        return businessUnit;
    }

    public void setBusinessUnit(TutenBusinessUnit businessUnit) {
        this.businessUnit = businessUnit;
    }
}
```

**TutenCaseCore (ejemplo de entidad hija)**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tuten_case_core")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "TutenCaseCore.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TutenCaseCore t"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TutenCaseCore.findById", query = "SELECT t FROM TutenCaseCore t WHERE t.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TutenCaseCore.findByCreationDate", query = "SELECT t FROM TutenCaseCore t WHERE t.creationDate = :creationDate")})
public class TutenCaseCore extends BussinesUnitParent implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "data")
    private String data;
    ...
}
```

**AbstractFacade (Clase abastracta donde tengo metodos genericos para obtener datos desde la BD)**

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public T find(Object id) {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<BussinesUnitParent> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(BussinesUnitParent.class);
        Root<BussinesUnitParent> bussinesUnitParentRoot = criteriaQuery.from(BussinesUnitParent.class);
        Root<T> root = criteriaBuilder.treat(bussinesUnitParentRoot, entityClass); // Esta es la linea del problema
        return null; 
    }
  ...
}
```

El problema es que al momento de declarar los Roots en el método find de la clase AbstractFacade al compilar me dice que no existe método treat para los parámetros especificados, siendo que en la documentación especifica lo siguiente

> treat(Root root, Class type) 
>   Downcast Path object to the specified type. 
>   https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#treat-javax.persistence.criteria.Root-java.lang.Class-

Tal vez estoy cometiendo algún error, o mal interpretando la api, necesito ayuda para aclarar este problema, y si estoy implementandolo mal, alguna alternativa para poder lograr el mismo objetivo que es: poder abstraer las clases que acceden a estos métodos para poder hacer la misma consulta en cualquier entidad, con lo mismos condicionales.

**EDIT**
**Estas son las dependencias que estan relacianadas a mi ambiente JPA**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
  <version>7.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: ¿Qué librerías estás usando? La documentación del método te dice "Since: Java Persistence 2.1", lo cual significa que si usa JPA 2.0 no existirá ese método.

Comment: @SJuan76 en el edit estan las librerias